# Trouble deleting an item from a hash map

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class mainClass
{
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    static HashMap <ArrayList <Integer>, String> hMap;

    public static void createAHashMap()
    {
        System.out.print("Express the initial capacity: ");
        int initialCapacity = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Express the load factor: ");
        float loadFactor = keyboard.nextFloat();
        hMap = new HashMap <ArrayList <Integer>, String> (initialCapacity, loadFactor);      
    }

    public static void insertProduct()
    {   
        ArrayList <Integer> informations = new ArrayList <Integer> ();
        System.out.print("\nEnter product's barcode number: ");
        int barcodeNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        while (barcodeNumber < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong barcode number entry. Please try again: ");
        }
        informations.add(barcodeNumber);
        System.out.print("Enter product's amount: ");
        int productAmount = keyboard.nextInt();
        informations.add(productAmount);
        System.out.print("Enter product's price: ");
        int productPrice = keyboard.nextInt(); 
        informations.add(productPrice);
        System.out.print("Enter product's name: ");
        String productName = keyboard.next();   
        hMap.put(informations, productName);
    }   

    public static void displayProducts()
    {
        System.out.println("\nBarcode Number\tProduct Amount\tProduct Price\tProduct Name");
        for (Entry <ArrayList <Integer>, String> entry: hMap.entrySet()) 
        {           
            for(int itemNo: entry.getKey())
            {
                System.out.print(itemNo + "\t\t");
            }
            System.out.print(entry.getValue() + "\t\t");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void removeAProduct()
    {
        System.out.print("Express product name that you want to remove: ");
        String productName = keyboard.next();
        hMap.remove(productName);
    }

  /*  public static void updateAProduct()
    {
        System.out.print("Express product name that you want to update: ");
        String productName = keyboard.next();
        hMap.remove(productName);
        System.out.println("Enter again the product informations");
        insertProduct();
    }*/

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        createAHashMap();

        System.out.print("\nEnter '1' to add a product\n");
        System.out.print("Enter '2' to display products\n");
        System.out.print("Enter '3' to delete a product\n");
        System.out.print("Enter '4' to update a product\n");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");

        int entry = keyboard.nextInt();     
        while (entry != -99)
        {
            if (entry == 1)
            {
                insertProduct();
            }
            if (entry == 2)
            {
                displayProducts();
            }
            if (entry == 3 && hMap.size() != 0)
            {
                removeAProduct();
            }
            if (entry == 4 && hMap.size() != 0)
            {
                //updateAProduct();
            }
            System.out.print("\nExpress your new choice (Exit: -99): ");
            entry = keyboard.nextInt();
        }       
    }
}
```

I've created a hash map which contains product informations in a supermarket. However, I can't remove the products what I entered as product name. Clearly, I can't use remove method. What is the problem, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, you need to use an `Iterator` to **iterate** through the `Map` & delete the product. (Since the `Map` is indexed by an `ArrayList` of `Integer`s)

```
System.out.print("Express product name that you want to remove: ");

String productName = keyboard.next();
ArrayList <Integer> rKey = null;

for (Entry <ArrayList <Integer>, String> entry: hMap.entrySet())  {
    if (productName.equals(entry.getValue())) {
        rKey = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
}

if (rKey != null) {
    hMap.remove(rKey);
}
```

On the other hand, I think it's best if you change

```
static HashMap <ArrayList <Integer>, String> hMap;

...
hMap.put(informations, productName);
```

to

```
static HashMap <String, ArrayList <Integer>> hMap;

...
hMap.put(productName, informations);
```

This way, you could easily remove products from the `Map` by their **name**s:

```
hMap.remove(productName);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Sparta. I want to ask another question. What would happen if I wanted to remove with barcode number?

Comment: Well, a temporary solution would be to use the the first item of the `informations` arraylist, but I think you need a second `Map`, like `static HashMap <HashMap <String, Integer>, String> hMap;`. And you should consider indexing your `Map` by the product name, not by its informations.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

Ideally it is expected that the HashMap `key` should be something that uniquely identifies `value`. So in your case `String` should be the key and `ArrayList <Integer>`

Making it look like:
`static HashMap <String, ArrayList <Integer>> hMap;`

Regarding the issue with remove operation, [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#remove(java.lang.Object)) expects the argument as key i.e productName in your case as [remove()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java) is defined as:

```
public V remove(Object key) {
    Entry<K,V> e = removeEntryForKey(key);
    return (e == null ? null : e.value);
}
```

So once you make this change by interchaning key and value, your code should work just fine.